# Flutter performance of StatefulWidget and StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter, dart, stateful

I use a lot StatelessWidgets when I have to create "templates" of widgets that are used multiple times inside my app because the docs say so:

> Stateless widget are useful when the part of the user interface you
>   are describing does not depend on anything other than the
>   configuration information in the object itself and the BuildContext in
>   which the widget is inflated.

Here is an example:

```
class StepInputButton extends StatelessWidget {

  final int pos;
  final String value;

  const StepInputButton({
    this.pos,
    this.value
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      // Text, Icon and a tiny button
    );
  }

}
```

The above is good because I can use `const StepInputButton(val, "val"),` in the code with CONST which improves performances.

---

**PROBLEM**

I am using the famous `Provider` widget to manage the state and the page of my apps usually look like this:

```
class SuccessPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var prov = Provider.of<Type>(context);    
    return Scaffold(...); 
  }

}
```

That's a page of my app with Scaffold that has a Drawer, a float action button and an appTitle.
Here I use a StatelessWidget because I do not use setState() since provider does all the work for me. But still in the official flutter doc they say:

> For compositions that can change dynamically, e.g. due to having an
>   internal clock-driven state, or depending on some system state,
>   consider using StatefulWidget.

So do I have to change `class SuccessPage extends StatelessWidget` to `class SuccessPage extends StatefulWidget`? Do I get advantages?

*Note*: if you want to put the question in another way: should I use StatefulWidgets to create "app pages" whose state is going to change and StatelessWidgets for "reusable widgets" whose state doesn't change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`StatefulWidget` is necessary for when the widget itself is maintaining its own state. In the example you gave, the `Provider` package is handling the state for you, assuming you're using the correct provider type higher up the widget tree (for example, `ChangeNotifierProvider`). There also doesn't seem to be anything in this code that would benefit from having access to the widget's lifecycle, so you wouldn't need access to methods like `initState` or `dispose`.

As such, there's nothing for the widget itself to manage, so converting your class to be stateful is unnecessary.

One thing I might suggest, though, is to use a `Consumer` instead of calling `Provider.of` directly. A `Consumer` handles the call for you and removes any ambiguity on whether your widget will get updated when the `Provider` detects a state change.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've exactly told me what I needed. I do not need to access the state since Provider is doing it for me so I'll go stateless

Comment: @Abion47, in case I need to enter data using a Form (and record the data to a rest server after clicking in a save button), should I go to `StatefulWidget` or can I also do everything using a proper provider and a `StatelessWidget` ?

Comment: @Cristiano If you mean a provider as in the provider package, the `Consumer` you use is itself a `StatefulWidget` that handles rebuilding when the state changes, so if you handle form data entry through the provider/consumer then yes, your form widget can be stateless.

Comment: @Abion47, what's that ambiguity you mentioned about `Provider.of`?

Comment: @TiagoSantos The ambiguity as to whether the widget will get updated when calling `Provider.of`. (There isn't any in actuality as inherited widgets follow a set of rules as to whether their changes will update a widget, but those rules can be tricky to understand sometimes. If there's any doubt, just use `Consumer` instead.)

Answer (score 7):

**Keeping it simple:**

1. If you have ***non-`final`*** global variables in your widget then you need a `StatefulWidget`
2. If all global variables are ***`final`*** then you should use `StatelessWidget`;

**Reason:**

1. If your global variable is non final that means it is allowed to change and if it's value is changed that means state of your object(Widget) is changed (basic oops concept I am talking about). In such case you would like to call build method of your widget so that your changes get applied on the UI (if it matters for your UI). We do it by calling `setState();` and so we use `StatefulWidget` for such use-case.
2. If it is enough that once you initialize your global variable in constructor, you don't need to assign it any value in future then in such case use `StatelessWidget`.

*I have tried to keep it very simple and not technical enough so, if you still have any doubts please comment on this answer*.

Comment: Very good explaination, I understand you deserve a +1. So in my case the SuccessPage is good as a StatelessWidget because I have NO non-final variables and the state is handled OUTSIDE. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

You use `StatelessWidget` for widgets that don't change their state, that will stay the same all the time. Example, `appBar` is stateless.. The `build(...)` function of the `StatelessWidget` is called only once and no amount of changes in any `Variable(s)`, `Value(s)` or `Event(s)` can call it again.

Therefore, when you need to change state(ex value) then use `StatefulWidgets`, basically `StatelessWidget` is used for building UI widgets that are static